# Bash array of functions

Tags: arrays, bash, function

I'm trying to create an array of functions in order to iterate through each function in order.

```
declare -a FUNCTION
FUNCTION[1]="FUNCTION.A"
FUNCTION[2]="FUNCTION.B"
FUNCTION[3]="FUNCTION.C"

for i in "${!FUNCTION[@]}"; do
  ${FUNCTION[$i]};
done
```

This just prints out FUNCTION.A and says command not found. I need it to run the function. Suggestions?

Comment: This is because you didn't define function FUNCTION.A itself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a moron........ The function must apparently be above where its being called. Kinda annoying. I wish all the functions could reside at the bottom.

Answer (score 18):

Works fine for me.

```
declare -a FUNCTION
FUNCTION[1]="FUNCTION.A"
FUNCTION[2]="FUNCTION.B"
FUNCTION[3]="FUNCTION.C"

#Define one of the functions
FUNCTION.A() { echo "Inside of FUNCTION.A"; }


$ for i in "${!FUNCTION[@]}"; do   ${FUNCTION[$i]}; done
```

OUTPUT:

```
Inside of FUNCTION.A
FUNCTION.B: command not found
FUNCTION.C: command not found
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way that I think looks a lot better

```
funcs_to_test=( voltage_force_landing voltage_warn_critical )

for testP in "${funcs_to_test[@]}"
do  
    $testP
done
```

And make sure to have written your functions above where you call this code

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't always call the respective functions, it only prints the function name. To call the function you should write ${funcs_to_test[testP]} instead of $testP.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to define functions from names kept in an array and then call these functions *after* their definition:

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -a functions=( a b c )
for f in ${functions[@]}; do
    eval "$f() { 
              echo "Hello from $f" 
              # ...
          }"
    $f
done
```

Alternatively:

```
#!/bin/sh

declare -a functions=( a b c )

a() { echo "Hello from $FUNCNAME"; }
b() { echo "Hello from $FUNCNAME"; }
c() { echo "Hello from $FUNCNAME"; }

for f in ${functions[@]}; do 
    $f
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare the function like this

```
FUNCTION=(FUNCTION.A FUNCTION.B FUNCTION.C)
```

And then iterate through it like this:

```
for i in "${!FUNCTION[@]}"; do
${FUNCTION[i]}
```

This should work. If you just call "$i" it will only print the functions name from the array.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that little nuisance, just put the body of the script into yet another function.   (I usually call it "app_main", because "main" is the name of the script's function as far as bash is concerned.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash # more portable

first() { echo "${FUNCNAME[0]}: $@" ; }
second() { echo "${FUNCNAME[0]}: $@" ; }

app_main() { 
    first "hello"
    second "goodbye" 17 3.14159
}

app_main
```